# CSS issue with floating images wrapped in anchor

Tags: css

I have a bunch of images defined in HTML, given a class of 'something-unique' and then via the magic of wordpress, they are wrapped with an anchor with no class or id to identify it by. I end up with...

```
<a href="http://test.com/DSC_0042.JPG" title="Details of image">
    <img class="picasa-image alignleft" width="150" height="150" alt="DSC_0042.JPG" src="http://picasa-image.url/s150-c/DSC_0042.JPG" title="Details of image">
</a>
```

I am able to set rules to my image by selecting with `.picasa-image` but when I float it left, it is ignored. When I remove the anchor tag, it floats correctly. When I float anchors left it floats correctly (but all other anchors on the page are floated).

How do I set the style of the anchor tag containing my images in css.

Comment: Have you the URL, I imagine you have checked in Firebug (or similar) To see what is overriding the float:left?

Comment: I have used firebug, which tells me that the anchor has no `float` rules at all, and when I apply a float to the anchor's element style, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do so is override the rule that is not allowing you to float left the images with another more specific rule (e.g. with an higher selector specificity or with `!important` declaration)

Otherwise a workaround is to float left, as you said, all links with an image. Since you have not an ancestor selector in css you must target those links in some other way, with a specific selector attribute e.g.

```
a[href$=".JPG"] { float : left }
```

and you will target all links pointing to a .JPG or if those links start with www.test.com another possibility is to target

```
a[href^="http://test.com"] { float : left }
```

or just apply a class to those links.